# LUIS response throws error with Bad Request

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I have started integrating Luis into my BOT. The LUIS query works great in a browser, but when invoked through code, the response from LUIS GetResult throws an error.

The LUIS query is [here](https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v1/application?id=2d3e39d8-632a-4e00-bf2f-d98ea4b2ed79&subscription-key=subkey&q=where%20is%20my%20order%20TF00012878)

Source code of the dialog:

```
 [LuisModel("2d3e39d8-632a-4e00-bf2f-d98ea4b2ed79&", "subscription Key")]
    [Serializable]
    public class SupportDialog : LuisDialog<object>
    {

        [LuisIntent("")]
        public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Sorry, I dont understand what you need");
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }


        [LuisIntent("OrderStatus")]
        public async Task OrderStatus(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
        {
            var returnMsg = "You wanted to check the order status";
            var orderStatus = "Dispatched";
            var deliveryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);

            var entities = new List<EntityRecommendation>(result.Entities);
            if(entities.Any((entity)=> entity.Type == "Order"))
            {
                var orderEntity = entities.Where((entity) => entity.Type == "Order").FirstOrDefault();
                var resolutionStr = orderEntity.Resolution.FirstOrDefault().Value ?? null;
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resolutionStr))
                {
                    returnMsg = "Your order " + resolutionStr + " status is " + orderStatus + " and expected to deliver by " + deliveryDate.Humanize();
                }
            }

            await context.PostAsync(returnMsg);
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }

    }
```

MessageController Source Code:

```
 internal static IDialog<object> MakeRoot()
        {
            return Chain.From(() => new SupportDialog());
        }

        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
        {
            if (activity != null)
            {
                // one of these will have an interface and process it
                switch (activity.GetActivityType())
                {
                    case ActivityTypes.Message:
                        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, MakeRoot);
                        break;

                    case ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate:
                    case ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate:
                    case ActivityTypes.Typing:
                    case ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData:
                    default:
                        Trace.TraceError($"Unknown activity type ignored: {activity.GetActivityType()}");
                        break;
                }
            }
            return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
        }
```

I get the following error (partial extract only) in my BOT Emulator when trying to debug:

```
> Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code
> does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.LuisService.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Luis-ILuisService-QueryAsync>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Extensions.<QueryAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog`1.<MessageReceived>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__13.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n  
> at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter<T>.GetResult()\r\n
> at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.FromDialog`1.<ResumeAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__13.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n  
> at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter<T>.GetResult()\r\n
> at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog`1.<ResumeAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__13.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IDialogStack-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LocalizedDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringDialogTask`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__6`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__6`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n  
> at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__6`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializingDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUserTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the ampersand sign in your LuisModel.

I guess you copied it from the URL accidentally.

Also, change your subscription key that you posted inside your code, or else we'll steal it.

Comment: Sorry, but which ampersand sign are you referring to but i dont need to refer the direct LUIS model URL anywhere in my code, right ?

Comment: This one is a free trial subscription so wont last for very long ;)

Comment: I mean the "&" sign in your luismodel attribute. Try removing that, it's a typo.

Comment: this is embarrasing & very stupid :-(  that fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

> This below error may also come; when you publish LUIS app under **Staging slot**

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)
```

> So always publish your LUIS app under **Production slot**

And obviously you have to remove the ampersand(**&**) sign from your LuisModel ID.

Comment: I agree with the usage of Production slot vs. Staging slot - and I would append - make sure that Luis app train & publish is completed - Endpoint key and Application Id are available even before it happens

Answer (score 3):

There is one line of code that can throw a null reference exception:

```
var resolutionStr = orderEntity.Resolution.FirstOrDefault().Value ?? null;
```

Try to rewrite it the next way:

```
var resolutionStr = orderEntity.Resolution.FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
```

Comment: the problem is that when i try to debug it, it does not even goes inside the function. I have just tried commenting the whole part except the hardcoded return message and even then it throws the same error. It seems to be caused by the Luis Intent attribute itself :-(

Comment: please also attach the code from your API controller